# Favored Food of Thousands

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

**This riddle has been edited significantly from the original. The clues and goal are largely the same, but I changed the final objective from a location to a food, as the location was largely contrived. The clues were only edited to add clarity and reflect this change. As the core of the riddle is intact, I refrained from creating a new Question.**

*Served in the halls of Ler, Sar, and Lin,

In the palaces of Pot and Lini too!*

*Delivered to the booth of Tas, Berg, and Hon,

Eaten cold by Chaels at the peaceful pond*

*Served to the dience by the thousands,

and cannibalized by lazy thousands more*

*Nibbled by tics and onks as they sit silently,

and Dha shows many the way*

*Eaten by Dr. Tine during his grizzly surgeries,

Munched by the modern mutilator Yaf*

*Fed to rots who learn speech and tors who learn speeches,

and a favorite of the King Sley's  in Sin City*

What is this popular food?

Hint 1:

> Addendum to the first clue:
>   *But never served to Ump or Ama*,
>   *And despised by Deau and Eron*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, credit where it's due: a key observation was made by Braegh in comments below. If you like this answer, go and find something of Braegh's and upvote it. Now:

The first thing to notice is that

> all those mysterious non-words and non-names are (approximate) *right halves*. So in the first stanza we have the halls of **Hit**ler, **Cae**sar and **Sta**lin, and the palaces of **Pol** Pot and **Musso**lini. The second seems full of sports commentators: Bob **Cos**tas, Dick **En**berg, Vince **McMa**hon, and Al **Mi**chaels who famously commented on the "Miracle on Ice" at *Lake Placid*, NY. In the fourth stanza we have **are**nas and (grand?)**st**ands; **mys**tics and **m**onks and, presumably, the **Bud**dha. In the sixth we have  **par**rots and **ac**tors (not orators as I'd previously thought, for reasons that will become apparent), though I don't know who the -king -sley(s) might be nor whether I'm looking at -sin City or at Las Vegas. The hint at the end of the previous version of the question probably had either **deni**zens or **citi**zens, who are **fami**liar with (probably) this **st**ate or **est**ate. (It could be e.g. **inm**ate but that seems much less likely.)

[EDITED to add:]

> shoover suggests in comments that the King Sleys are imitators of Elvis **Pre**sley ("The King"), which seems very plausible; also that Deau and Eron are Pierre **Tru**deau and David **Cam**eron, which they might be though e.g. Felipe Calderon seems about as plausible as David Cameron. And OP explains that Tine is Dr **Guillo**tine (though his actual name was Guillotin...) and Yaf is Abu **Say**yaf of ISIS.

But what does this have to do with our mystery food? Well, "obviously" it's

> 'taters. That is, potatoes.

So we have

> *dic-tators* in the first stanza; *commen-tators* in the second; *spec-tators* in the third; *medi-tators* in the fourth; in the fifth, given OP's revelations described above, *decapi-tators*;  probably *imi-tators* in the sixth, which is why I think they are actors rather than orators.

I confess that I am not entirely convinced about Ama and Ump:

> Mr Obama, as a former academic, is surely a *cogitator*, and while few would describe Trump that way it would be hard to deny that he is an *agitator*.

Comment: I edited this question significantly, as the location was very contrived. You are on the right track.

Comment: Wow, I'd completely forgotten about this one. Will take another look now it's been modified.

Comment: (My immediate reaction is that the food is probably **'za**, for the obvious suffixy reason, but I suspect there's more going on than that.)

Comment: I suspect we might be looking for something along the lines of rot13(cbgngbrf) considering the first stanza describes rot13(qvpgngbef). I can't quite fit the remainder of the stanzas in, though...

Comment: D'oh, you're obviously right. Editing answer appropriately. (The key is an abbreviation.) [EDITED to add:] Done now.

Comment: Deau is rot13(Whfgva be Cvreer Gehqrnh bs Pnanqn). King Sley is rot13(Gur Xvat bs Ebpx naq Ebyy, Ryivf Cerfyrl). Eron is rot13(Qnivq Pnzreba bs gur HX).

Comment: And they are all anti- the thing that the first set are.

Comment: Those are all plausible candidates. And yes, it was clear what *sort* of people Deau and Eron would have to be. It's not obvious, though, why e.g. your proposed Eron is better than rot13(Sryvcr Pnyqreba).

Comment: Cheers! I knew once it was a better riddle it would be solvable. Stanza 5 (the gruesome one) describes the "grizzly surgeries" (i.e. decapitations) of the guillotine, invented by Dr. Guillotine, then Abu Sayyaf was the "Chief Decapitator" for ISIS.

Comment: Aha! I should totally have thought of that. Not that I'd heard of Abu Sayyaf.

Comment: And wait, how are Tine and Yaf contemporaries in that case?

Comment: Yikes. They are definitely not. Apologies for the deception -- editing to change.

Comment: Answer tweaked accordingly.

Comment: Er, also, his actual name was Guillotin rather than Guillotine. Just out of curiosity, what was the place we were supposed to find in the original version? Presumably it sounds something like "tator" but I'm failing to think what it might be.

Comment: Oh no, it was terribly contrived. I tried to pick a place where potatoes would be found. A land of potatoes. Two candidates emerged: Ireland and Idaho. I picked Idaho, and the "citizens" (i.e. the potatoes) are familiar with this state. State being Idaho, and the right-half of Idaho is a ho(e), which, again, terribly contrived. Hence the edits.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, the new version is indeed better :-).